# Disable PAY Button when status "paid"

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to disable pay button when status paid.

**My Code:**

```
<table id="simple-table" class="table  table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="30%">Month </th>
            <th width="20%">DPS Amount</th>
            <th width="20%">Status</th>
            <th width="30%">Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php
                    $acc=$_GET['acc'];
                    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dps_schedule WHERE account_number= :userid");
                    $result->bindParam(':userid', $acc);
                    $result->execute();
                    $counter = 0;
                    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
            ?>
        <tr class="record">
            <td>Month-<?php echo ++$counter; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['dps_payment']; ?></td>
            <td class="status"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
            <td class="dis"><a rel="facebox" href="dps_installment.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-success btn-mini"><i class="icon-edit"></i> PAY </button></a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Code View:**

[image]

Now want to disable pay button when status paid.

Comment: You can add if condition like <?php if($row['status']!="Paid"){ ?> Pay Button will come <?php } ?>

Comment: why not to hide for paid button? you want disable only? because disable can enable easily

Comment: you want to hide or disable??

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh is right. You must show or hide Pay button only, not to disable.

Comment: Remember - client side validation or restriction is only a convinience to the user, you **must** verify actions on the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add if condition like below if you don't want to show Pay Button for Paid Orders :

```
<?php if($row['status']!="Paid"){ ?> 
    <td class="dis"><a rel="facebox" href="dps_installment.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-success btn-mini"><i class="icon-edit"></i> PAY </button></a></td> 
<?php } ?>
```

You can also show the button as Paid and remove the link over it with if else condition like below:

```
<?php if($row['status']=="Paid"){ ?> 
    <td class="dis"><button class="btn btn-success btn-mini"><i class="icon-edit"></i> PAID </button></td>
<?php } else { ?>
    <td class="dis"><a rel="facebox" href="dps_installment.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-success btn-mini"><i class="icon-edit">
</i> PAY </button></a></td> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="dis"><a rel="facebox" href="dps_installment.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-success btn-mini"><i class="icon-edit"></i> PAY </button></a></td>
```

to

```
<td class="dis"><a rel="facebox" href="dps_installment.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-success btn-mini <?php if($row['status'] =="paid"){ echo "disabled";}?>"><i class="icon-edit"></i> PAY </button></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="simple-table" class="table  table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="30%">Month </th>
        <th width="20%">DPS Amount</th>
        <th width="20%">Status</th>
        <th width="30%">Options</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <?php
                $acc=$_GET['acc'];
                $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dps_schedule WHERE account_number= :userid");
                $result->bindParam(':userid', $acc);
                $result->execute();
                $counter = 0;
                $button = '<button class="btn btn-success btn-mini"><i class="icon-edit"></i> PAY </button>';
                for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){                       
                    if( $row['status']=='unpaid') $sbutton = '<a rel="facebox" href="dps_installment.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$button.'</a>'; //check here the status if unpaid add button with link                        
        ?>
    <tr class="record">
        <td>Month-<?php echo ++$counter; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dps_payment']; ?></td>
        <td class="status"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
        <td class="dis"><?php echo $sbutton; ?></td><!--Add $sbutton here with contain link-->
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
</tbody>
```